# Conditional probability of incorrectly weighing produce, given it is done by a specific employee

Tags: probability

A food store has 3 employees who package & weigh produce. Employees A,B and C record correct weight 98%, 97% and 95% of the time respectively. Employees A,B and C handle 50%, 30% and 20% of the packaging respectively. A customer complains about incorrect weight on a package she has purchased. What is the probability that the packaging was weighed by employee B.

Let $W$= correctly weighed, $\bar W$= incorrectly weighed

Given:

$P(A)=0.5, P(B)=0.3, P(C)=0.2$

$P(W|A)=0.98, P(W|B)=0.97, P(W|C)=0.95$ and we can deduce $P(\bar W|B)=1-0.97=0.03$

Therefore, $P(\bar W \cap B)=P(\bar W|B)P(B)=0.03*0.3=0.009=0.9$%

Is my reasoning correct? I just felt that a lot of information was given that I did not use to solve this. Or may be I missed something? Also apologize for the vague title. It is difficult to come up with a good title with these probability problems. Appreciate your help and any edits.

Comment: That seems low, no?  Work it out for $A,C$ as well.   These three probabilities must add to $1$.

Comment: Don't forget, you are given that it was incorrectly weighed.  Thus you need a denominator.

Comment: Got it! I missed that part while solving the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to find the probability that it was weighted by employee $B$ **given** that it was incorrectly weighted.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
P(B \mid W^c)
&=\frac{P(B \cap W^c)}{P(W^c)}\\\\
&=\frac{0.3\cdot0.03}{0.5\cdot0.02+0.3\cdot0.03+0.2\cdot0.05}\\\\
&\approx 0.3103
\end{align*}$$

The denominator can be thought of as a weighted average.